# Flutter build.gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, build

I am a newbie to Flutter.  Just wanna ask how many build.gradle files are in a Flutter project; what is Project-level and App-level build.gradle?  Thanks in advance.

I found 2:

> android > app > build.gradle
 > android > app > src > build.gradle

Answer (score 1):

In a Flutter project, there are two build.gradle files: one at the project-level and one at the app-level.

The project-level build.gradle file is located in the root directory of your Flutter project and is used to define the properties and settings for the entire project. This file is usually used to configure the repositories and dependencies for your Flutter project as a whole.

The app-level build.gradle file is located in the android directory within your Flutter project and is used to define the properties and settings specific to your Android app. This file is used to configure the app-level dependencies and build settings.

So in summary, there are two build.gradle files in a Flutter project: one at the project-level and one at the app-level.

Comment: I can't find build.gradle in the root level (the level where pubspec.yaml locates), should I create one?  There is a build.gradle inside android-> app,  but there is another build.gradle inside android-> app-> src, which one is the app level gradle files?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Flutter. That's typical Android project structure.